# Is it okay to redirect all mobile users to a mobile coming soon page?

Tags: redirects, mobile

I recently read [this article](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/blogspot/amDG/~3/2cKmN-l1KtU/changes-in-rankings-of-smartphone_11.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email) on google webmasters blog which said that we should avoid redirection of users on mobile to one single page as it interrupts their flow.

Now I have a site on which I have a mobile coming soon page to which a user is redirected the first time he/she visits the site. Once a user clicks "view web version" on this page a cookie is set and he/she is taken to the homepage. Now if the user comes again on my site he/she would be taken to that respective page and wouldn't be redirected.

Can this have SEO penalties? I am not interrupting the user-flow every-time and hence should I bother much?

Should I scrap this all together or alternatively I could redirect the user to the page they came to when they click "view web version" instead of the homepage?

Comment: Please don't. Smart phones already do an excellent job of supporting non-mobile web pages. Leave choice as most "mobile aware" designs actually do a far worse job of presenting your website than a properly designed computer browser user interface. Leave the decision up to the user as to whether they want a supposedly better "mobile" web version or your standard website.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** While you will have no SEO penalty if you include the [User-Agent: Vary](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects) in your HTTP response, this is detrimental to your users. If this leads to a significant change bounce rate, you may eventually lose some ranking.

**Anything you show to your users is better than not showing them anything**. A coming soon page does little to respond to your user's needs at the time they visit. Better redirect them when your page is up and have a small banner on your webpage saying a mobile version is coming if you really want to pre-announce it. But, really, pre-announcements do not do much for sites without some huge followings in the first place.